# When is a semi-structured data model more appropriate than a structured one?

Tags: xml, database, relational-database, non-relational-database

Let's consider a semi-structured data model like XML and a structured one like the well known relational data model.

**When is better to store the data in a XML database instead of a relational dbms ?**

It obviously depend on the kind of data that we want to manage, but is there a specific kind of data for which it is definitely better to use a XML database?

The only advantage I can see with XML is that we can save memory if we have entities with a lot of null values which change only in respect to the value of an attribute 'type'.
In a XML file we simply do not store the attributes that would be null in a relational table.

It seems to me that there is a lot more to that, but I am clueless.

Comment: What's a semi-structured data model?

Comment: It's basically a tree structure with an arbitrary number of children for each node.

Comment: @Max That’s also structured data. And isn’t the answer to your question simply: “when you have semi-structured data”?

Comment: It's probably this that I can not grasp properly. For what I got so far, a tree (I am thinking to XML) is a semi-structured data model because you can not assume that a certain kind of node will be present under another node. On the other hand, in a table every column is always present.

Comment: An XML schema impose structure on those trees, just like a database schema imposes structure on data stored in tables. So in that sense, you *can* rely on a certain kind of node being present where it's expected, and nowhere else.

Comment: Ok, but I have read that an XML schema is not mandatory and this gives us the flexibility of semi-strucutured data. What you can do with these 2 data model is really similar and that's why I can not find the differences.

Answer (score 1):

A semi-structured data model is optimal for one kind of data only: semi-structured data.

That is, when you have structured data of the following form:

```
<node>
    <text>foo</text>
    <bold>
        <text>bar</text>
    </bold>
    <text>baz</text>
</node>
```

then it makes sense to compress the representation by getting rid of the redundant “text” nodes:

```
<node>
    foo
    <bold>bar</bold>
    baz
</node>
```

This is all that XML avails you over strictly structured data representations. Essentially, that’s what documents are (in particular HTML).

Note that this is only about *representation*. The two above data models are *equivalent*, and both are represented by a tree.

Comment: Thank you, but isn't this still a matter of memory saving?

Comment: It may save memory, but only coincidentally. More importantly it makes the document much more readable (for humans). If you are not concerned with human readability all of this is moot, just use structured data.